# how to compute total free physical memory on hp-ux

Tags: c, hp-ux

I would like to either make a shell script or c program that computes the free memory in similar fashion as command `free` does on linux, for hp-ux.

On hp-ux default installation, only commands that I know which can calculate the free memory are vmstat, or eventually top.

Is there any c api that allows user to calculate all free memory? Or eventually a way to determine all physical memory available on system, then sum all used memory and calculate free PHYS memory?

Comment: Run `tusc vmstat` to find out how vmstat does it. There needs to be a system call.

Answer (score 1):

I do it with this little program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/pstat.h>

int main () {
    struct pst_static pst;
    struct pst_dynamic psd;

    memset(&pst,0,sizeof(struct pst_static));
    pstat_getstatic(&pst, sizeof(pst), (size_t)1, 0);

    memset(&psd,0,sizeof(struct pst_dynamic));
    pstat_getdynamic(&psd, sizeof(psd), (size_t)1, 0);

    printf("Total Memory: %lld\n",pst.physical_memory * pst.page_size);
    printf("Free Memory: %lld\n",psd.psd_free * pst.page_size);
}
```

It outputs the total and the free memory.

See also the HP-UX manual page for `pstat`.